# 502 Bad Gateway ngnix on Ubuntu server after reboot

Tags: ubuntu

I have web API on ubuntu server running on 80 port.
When I use  curl http://localhost:80
it's looks ok - If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.

When I use postman to use API I have only 502, what should I do? It was working before I rebooted the server.